# Doctrine: Remove owning side but not the inversed

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities which have one-to-many and many-to-one relationship.

CourseTopic:

```
<one-to-many field="participants" target-entity="Participant" mappedby="courseTopic"/>
```

Participant:

```
<many-to-one field="courseTopic" target-entity="CourseTopic" fetch="LAZY" inversed-by="participants">
    <join-columns>
       <join-column name="course_topic_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
    </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
```

So basically I can remove participants as long as there will be one that will remain. But if I am to remove every participant doctrine also deletes the inversed side. How can I prevent that?

Comment: What do you mean by  "deletes the inversed side"? The entity `CourseTopic` is being removed at all when you remove a link with `Participant`? Even in database?

Comment: @DmitryMalyshenko When all of the Participants are removed, yes the CourseTopic is also deleted in the database. Is that how it is supposed to be?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Could you provide the code that shows the issue?

Comment: @dragoste It is just a simple remove using the entity manager. Actually I receive a a Foreign key violation exception because it can't delete the Course Topic because of a foreign key constraint. What I would want is to be able to delete all of the Participant and the Course Topic participants field should be empty by then.

Comment: Didn't you set `nullable:false` on this association? Because it's `true` by default.